# RCP - Proper register Listener not from view

Tags: eclipse-rcp, listener

I try to register my class as `PostSelectionListener` from separate plugin (this class is not a view, only simple class), I use this:

```
Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().
    addPostSelectionListener(VIEWS_VISUALIZATION_TYP_ID, this);
```

It works fine, but I have a warning:

```
- Discouraged access: The method getActiveWorkbenchWindow() 
from the type Workbench is not accessible due to restriction on required library F:
  \elipseSource\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.5.1.M20090826-0800a.jar
- Discouraged access: The method getInstance() 
from the type Workbench is not accessible due to restriction on required library F:\elipseSource\plugins
  \org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.5.1.M20090826-0800a.jar
- Discouraged access: The type Workbench is not accessible 
due to restriction on required library F:\elipseSource\plugins
  \org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.5.1.M20090826-0800a.jar
```

How can I register listener in proper way ?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution, instead of

> Workbench.getInstance()

I should use:

> PlatformUI.getWorkbench()

I am RCP beginner so it was not obvious for me

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. +1. I have updated my answer to reflect that solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check if this is a `MANFEST.MF` generation issue (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.emf/msg18952.html))

> Open the `MANIFEST.MF` of the base project and look at the Runtime tab.
>   The packages that are to be accessed in other plugins should be listed as Exported Packages.

Try to re-compute the right list of exported packages.

If this is not working, as described in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.pde/msg02088.html), you still have the option to [de-activate the warning](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html):

- Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings
- (or: Project) Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

[image]

> "Warning" or "Ignore" options will only hide the potential issue in the project, by allowing the project to use any classes ignoring predefined access rules.
>   To completely resolve this issue, analyze the project and located the use of restricted classes and take necessary actions (either remove those references or access rules).

---

For external jar (not your case), [Potential workaround](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg24579.html):

> If I add the Jar file as an external jar and move it up before the JRE system Library (in order of export), I don't get this error.

---

Actually the OP [slowik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266146/slowik) managed to avoid the dependency by accessing the `Workbench` services through the `PlatformUI`

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
```

<sup>instead of `Workbench.getInstance()`</sup>

You can see this approach used in the [`rcp.util.RCPUtil`](http://kickjava.com/src/com/nightlabs/rcp/util/RCPUtil.java.htm#ixzz0ibk0Chur) class:

```
/**
 * Returns wether the ViewPart with the given id is currently visble in
 * one of the pages of the active Workbench window. Will also return
 * true when the page-book containing this view is minimized.
 *
 * @param viewID The id of the view to be queried
 * @return Wether the view is visible
 */
 public static boolean isViewVisible(String JavaDoc viewID) {
   // IWorkbenchPage[] pages = Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPages();
   IWorkbenchPage[] pages = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPages();
   for (int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
     IWorkbenchPart part = pages[i].findView(viewID);
     if (part != null) {
       return isPartVisible(part);
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: See also http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse-UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/WorkbenchConfigurer.java.shtml